# Java SOAP Service & GlassFish

Tags: java, web-services, soap, glassfish

How can I deploy a simple Java SOAP Service To GlassFish server .
My Service;-

```
    import testlib.test.*;
    @WebService
    @SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
    public class TestWS {
        public String testCall(@WebParam(partName = "TestStr") String inStr)  {

            testlib.test.Tester test=new testlib.test.Tester();
            return "You Sent"+inStr;
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the following error 
 
Note : If I Comment this testlib.test.Tester test=new testlib.test.Tester(); it work without error 
Exceptions details
 :

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at